# Android build doesn't update code base or resources for target .apk on device

Tags: android

I have an android project to make a simple game that was proceeding normally, until a teammate decided to swap out an audio clip.  I put the new .ogg file in the /res/raw folder and updated  all references in the program to point to the new file.  Rebuilding the program and installing it, the program still uses the old sound.  This is true for multiple devices as well as virtual ones.

Since then, no change I have made to the code base has made any change to the program that gets installed.

Even when I delete the application from the device completely, and rebuild, nothing changes.

The old audio file itself has been completely been deleted from my computer, but every time I rebuild and install, the old file plays.

Where is this cached copy being stored, and how do I delete it?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean rebuild from your IDE?

Comment: i have tried, and now it gives me the "can't find .apk" error.  Now I am going to delete the project and try to restore it