# Android Studio not reflecting changes

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an Android app using Android Studio. The problem is that after I changed my code and run the studio, some time the changed version is not reflecting in my device.

Here is what I've tried and solved my problem...

```
1. Build > Clean Project > Run
2. Build > Rebuild Project > Run
3. Restart device
```

Do i all time tried this procedure for reflecting the latest code change? 
It is very boring...
I have read the following:

[Android Studio is installing old apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831082/android-studio-is-installing-old-apk-on-device)

Comment: Which AS version are you using? Have you tried disabling Instant Run? Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.

Comment: Report that problem to them

Comment: android studio version is 1.5.1 and Instant Run is not visible in Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option called "Instant Run" in android studio that decreases the time of build process. If you use it, it may cause the problem. Try to turn it off.

I'm using **Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5** and gradle 2.10 and I recommend using this version or above.

Comment: i am using android studio version is 1.5.1 and Instant Run is not visible. So do i need to update the android studio?

Comment: As android studio is a fast forwarding IDE, I recommend using the latest version of Android Studio, I used to have many difficulties with older versions.

Comment: Also using latest SDK tools and plugins

Answer (score 1):

Turning off "Instant Run" will not be good idea if your app is huge.

Try following:

1. "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ...".
2. If you are using gradle 6.0 (it has a bug) use another version of gradle.
3. Go to "Run > Edit Configuration" and under "Before launch:" add "Gradle-aware Make" as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same Issue. Changed my code in Android Studio and start debugging to verify my implementation. Breakpoints were not hit and nothing of my changes were applied. For me, adding

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

to `build.gradle` helped.

Answer (score -1):

First...Clean the project and then rebuild it.
If this doesn't works then try to clean cache of Android studio in file menu.