# How to run the same project multiple times in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am developing client side of my application using IntelliJ IDEA. For debugging I need to run multiple clients.

I guess running same projects in different windows is not possible with IntelliJ IDEA. So how do I run multiple clients for debugging?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [run or debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-android-applications.html) the same [Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) in IntelliJ IDEA several times if you enable the [Allow parallel run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rceEE.png) checkbox.

You will see a tab per instance in the Run or Debug tool window.

In the previous IDE versions this checkbox was called **Single instance only** and its effect was reversed.